# How to structure an embedded application while decoupling application and driver code for a peripheral (UART)?

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, uart, hal

So I'm writing drivers for UART on STM32 and even though I kind of have an idea on laying out the structure, I'd still want to clarify prior to implementing, and also considering how essential it is to keep the code clean and organized.

So I have `main.c`, `sensor.c` (application file that uses UART layer), `hal_usart.c` (which is the driver file).

I have heard different things regarding how application code should have no clue whatsoever about the driver APIs, and read up an article the other day that you could decouple the sensor code from HAL driver code using function pointers but not sure how I could do that here, and if that will decouple it considering I'm still passing a reference to USART_Handle struct that contains info like baudRate, parityControl, wordLength, reference to `USART_TypeDef` etc.

Below is a snippet of my idea:

```
// main.c
static USART_Handle pUSART;

int main(void) {
   // initialize clocks/HAL 

   // ...initialize USART struct

   // Get data via UART (calling application API)
   GetData(&pUSART);   
}

// sensor.c (application)
void GetData(USART_Handle *pUSART) {
     HAL_USART_TX(); 
     HAL_USART_RX();   // assuming data is stored in one of the struct members
}

// hal_usart.c  (Driver file)
void HAL_USART_TX() {} 
void HAL_USART_RX() {}
```

Comment: ***`void`*** `HAL_USART_TX()` sounds bad.  `// assuming data is stored in one of the struct members` even worse.

Comment: That wasn't the main gist of the question, but since you asked, I think you're referring to `HAL_USART_RX()`. And that's just a sample code and I didn't bother putting correct return types but what's wrong with storing data in one of the struct members?

Answer (score 1):

Since you would like to separate Application code and Driver code in an embedded system, I suggest you study how to implement callback functions in C also embedded systems.

Here is the [reference](https://www.beningo.com/embedded-basics-callback-functions/).

Answer (score 1):

The utility of function pointers is maximum when you want to change the pointer while the program is running; or, in other words, when you have at least two different functions and, based on some condition, you want to use one or another.

For example, let's say you have a routine which reads a sensor using a serial port, and the user can switch from a sensor to another (two serial ports or even two different methods). In that case, the sensor routine could call a function, to read, using a function pointer, and manage the back read data. The main program, by changing the function pointer, can instruct the sensor routine to use one or the other sensor.

If you don't need to change things at runtime, you can simply write your sensor routine making it call a reading function (external) defined in some other file. The documentation of the sensor routine simply has to state that somewhere must be defined a routine called "int sensor_get_data()".

This involves to design your own "internal protocol" based on what data goes and comes from the "detached drivers". For example, the sensor routine, which copes with a precise model of a sensor, can have the need to send a command and receive a response. You can write your sensor routine which construct the command and decodes the answer, and take away the low level details wrapping all them in the single function "int sensor_get_data(int command)". You then link or include the sensor code, and implement the function sensor_get_data() in the main.

The main() does not know the details of the sensor, it only knows that the sensor code, when needed, will call the function sensor_get_data(). But this function can use an UART, or an i2c or a spi, without the sensor routine even noticing that; moreover, this routine can use any of the three ports, perhaps basing on parameters the user can modify at runtime.

All this can be named "callback mechanism", and implements a sort of separation between declaration and implementation, as mentioned in the other answer. What I depicted is not different from that, but it is *static* - the program is compiled with a fixed callback, instead of passing a function pointer in every call.

Comment: well, in my sensor file, I have "int _get_data()" that's basically a wrapper around a HAL API "HAL_I2C_read_data_interrupts()" defined inside "hal_i2c.c" which is a low-level driver file. So technically I don't have any driver-specific low-level details inside the sensor file -- just the HAL function call for getting the data and then processing it as per the sensor datasheet. from what I understand, this is what you originally meant?

Comment: @xyf no: I mean that sensor.c calls the routine get_data() which is defined in main.c, and get_data() calls the HAL. sensor.c knows nothing about the physical layer, up to the point that main.c could even replay data or invent it, for example for testing or simulation purposes.

Comment: shouldn't the flow be from `main` to an application file `sensor`.c` than the other way around?

Comment: @xyf mostly yes. But what I said still applies, I think, in order to achieve the decoupling. The main, whenever it wants, calls sensor.c; sensor.c calls back the main because sensor.c does not know how to do I/O. The main can not fetch data to pass to sensor.c, because main does not know what and how to ask. So main asks sensor.c to do its work, and sensor.c asks main for help...